# Overwrite Function at Runtime

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript so excuse me if I'm missing something obvious.

I would like to change a function at runtime that is deeply nested in other objects.

I'm wondering if there's a way to find out where in the tree the function is located, or somehow translate the breakpoint into a file or memory offset, so I can change the function with a user script once it is loaded.

Comment: do you have a reference to one of those objects?

Comment: I don't know the exact path to the function in the tree. Is it inside of an anonymous function, which is part of an array of several thousands of anonymous functions, which is a child of the window object. I looked into getting a reference to the parent object of the function, but that doesn't seem to be possible in JavaScript.

Comment: If the source code of this function doesn't change, you may traverse the tree and search for it using `Function.prototype.toString`

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: If you have the reference to the function in question, let's call it `myFunction`, you can do `myFunction.toString()`, then traverse `window` the object node by node, and calling `.toString()` on all functions you find, and compare the strings. Note that the `window` object is huge and will probably have lots of circular references which you'll have to ignore. But I'm sure there are much easier ways to approach what ever you are trying to do. Can you share more details?

Comment: Is it from a library or a built-in function?

Comment: How would I traverse the window object looking only at functions? Would I be able to get the full path down to the window object from doing that?

The function is part of a website's JavaScript code, so it's not a builtin.